# grid div positioning differently on mobile for some columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I need to make a page that has a different structure on mobile  than on web.
The web version is always reversed like so :

> text webm
>
> webm text
>
> text webm
>
> webm text

And the mobile version is regular like so:

> text
>
> webm
>
> text
>
> webm

My current structure suits my needs for web and is following:

```
<div class="row text-left">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    Mytext
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <%= video_tag('hiw_r_1.webm', autoplay: true, loop: true) %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-right">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <%= video_tag('hiw_r_2.webm', autoplay: true, loop: true) %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    Mytext
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-left">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <%= video_tag('hiw_r_3.webm', autoplay: true, loop: true) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the result this yields is

> text
>
> webm
>
> webm
>
> text
>
> text
>
> webm

Now, I know I can "hack" to make this work, just add columns hidden for mobile that include the webm's every time text goes second and just hide the first webm's on mobile. Although, this would mean that the page had to load almost double the load of all the videos, which is undesireable.

Is there another way to achieve this by manipulating the structure instead of adding additional webms and hiding and showing based on a media query?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With proper use of classnaming, you could apply some flex-box rules that can easily reverse the direction of the columns in a row

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lalji Tadhani in the comments I was able to figure out how to fix this issue.

The main problem in my thinking was not thinking mobile first.

You can apperantly pull and push lg columns. As soon as I knew this a solution was easy.

Every reverse column on lg screen I added

```
col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-xs-12
```

And the second col in that row was

```
col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-xs-12
```

The structure was right on XS, and then I pushed and pulled the cols for larger screen into place.